# Error connecting to server outside database in django

Tags: postgresql

I use external postgreSQL server in django

Test on iPhone to check external connection
It is normally connected from the outside. [external_connection_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EAZe2.jpg)

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'project5',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': '112.156.243.133',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

I set up the django database with the same dsn as I tested on iPhone.

but django web server can't connect to database.

**error code**

> could not connect to server: Connection refused
> Is the server running on host "112.156.243.133" and accepting
> TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Why doesn't it connect?

Comment: In case you're using the real IP and credentials, please consider obfuscating them :)

Comment: You have two different IP addresses shown in your question. I can connect to the 133 one (not the 129 one) on my laptop

Comment: You need to get on the webserver and do some tests. Do you have access to the webserver? _Firewall is allowed. Ports are also open_ clearly this is not the case

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when I get errors like this, it is usually due to a Firewall port that needs to be opened on inbound/outbound requests.

If you've tried everything, but it's still not working, then you'll need to ssh into the web server. Then run a packet `tracert` from the web server to the DB server. You'll be able to see where the packets are getting dropped, which should shed some light on the problem.

You could also try disabling the Firewall completely, to rule it out as a culprit.

Comment: Firewall is allowed. Ports are also open

Comment: Maybe the IP address of the web server needs to be whitelisted within the DB server's Firewall as well.